# Quitting a new job on short notice in a professional way

Tags: professionalism, resignation, canada

My girlfriend recently has got herself into a bit of a dilemma. She recently got a job at a grocery store in Canada where she has now worked 2 shifts (1 for training, 1 regular shift).  At the same time, she was offered a job at a clothing store.

She would much prefer this job as it is closer to her home, interests her more, and is less physically demanding. She has only worked at the grocery store for one week.

What is the most professional way to quit the grocery job after such a short period of time?

Comment: What does her contract say?

Comment: @nvoigt seems she needs to give 2 weeks notice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the most professional way to quit the grocery job after such a short period of time?

She should hand in a letter of resignation with the date of resignation and her last day of work ( honoring the agreed upon notice period ).

Also, if she already has not done so, she needs to inform the new company that she would not be able to start until her notice period at her current company is over.

It's possible her current company may let her go before her notice period is over.  In this case, she can inform the new company and they may be willing to accelerate her start date.